# Product of $2$ permutations

Tags: permutations

> $(2,3)(4,6,5,1,2)=?$

The multiplication is from right to left. I don't know, where I make the mistake.

Denote $\tau=(2,3), \sigma=(4,6,5,1,2)$

$1\ \ 2\ \ 3\ \ 4\ \ 5\ \ 6$$\quad$ first apply $\sigma$

$2\ \ 4\ \ 3\ \ 6\ \ 1\ \ 5$$\quad$ then $\tau$

$2\ \ 3\ \ 4\ \ 6\ \ 1\ \ 5$

$\Rightarrow (2,3)(4,6,5,1,2)=(1,2,3,4,6,5)$

I think this form is correct (If I convert the cycle notation to one-line notation, compose the permutations and then convert it back to cycle-form), but I want to derive it directly from the cycle notation, why does it fail ?

$1)$ $4$ goes to $6$ and $\tau$ does nothing to $6$, $\Rightarrow (4,6,...)$

$2)$ $6$ goes to $5$ and $\tau$ again fixes $5$, $\Rightarrow (4,6,5,..)$

$\dots\Rightarrow (4,6,5,1,...)$

Now $1$ goes to $2$ and $\tau$ sends $2$ to $3$ $\Rightarrow (4,6,5,1,\color{red}{3}..)$

am I wrong ?

Comment: What you're doing wrong is in the first part you assume the permutation works on specific _positions_ while in the second part you assume permutations work on specific _elements_. You can see this because in the first part, $\tau$ swaps $3$ and $4$, since they are the numbers in positions $2$ and $3$, while below you say "$1$ goes to $2$ and $\tau$ sends $2$ to $3$".

Comment: @Arthur you mean the 3rd line of the first computation should be $3\ 4\ 2\ 6\ 1\ 5$ ?

Comment: Exactly which one of them is _correct_ is up to your professor / the author of your book / your personal preference, but yes, that would make your two arguments agree.

Comment: @Arthur. Thanks a lot, such a mistake could be fatal in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's $(4,6,5,1,3,2)$. If you plot the big cycle and the small transposition, the effect is an implant on the initial cycle, giving a bigger one.